# How to cope with int overflow

Tags: c++, casting, int, overflow, long-integer

I have this code and I am trying to avoid the overflow of the int type. When I input 
 {1000000,1000000} I get 0 instead of 1. This is caused by the overflow of the int type. I am trying to cast it somehow but It doesn't work, please help.

Best regards!

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SplitIntoPairs {
public:
    int makepairs(vector<int> A, int X)
    {

        int s = 0;
        sort(A.begin(), A.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < A.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            int k = A[i] * A[i + 1]; //bool b = true;
            if (A[i] * A[i + 1] > 2147483647) {
                k = (long long)(k);
                //  b=false;
            }
            if (k >= X)
                ++s;
        }
        //return the created int
        return s;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`A[i] * A[i + 1]` is performing an integer operation, and so it will overflow with large values in `A`, making the comparison to 2147483647 before the cast not work properly.

If you cast the values in `A` up to the long before performing your multiplication, you won't even need the comparison. For example:

```
long long k = (long long)(A[i]) * (long long)(A[i + 1]);
if (k >= X)
    ++s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have choosen the right direction - store product in 64 bit integer but you have to consider that multipling 32 bit integers you receive 32 bit integer. All you need is to convert 32 bit integer to 64 bit integer before multiplication

```
int makepairs(std::vector<int> A, int X)
{
    int s = 0;
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size() - 1; i += 2) {
        long long k = ((long long) A[i]) * A[i + 1];        
        if (k >= X)
            ++s;
    }
    //return the created int
    return s;
}
```